# Filter Specific Column Number in Excel

Tags: excel, vbscript

I want to filter a specific column, `CS`, in Excel using VBScript. This is what I have so far. I basically want to filter column `CS` with the string `statusGiven`.

```
wb.Sheets("Profile").Range("A1:DD500").AutoFilter 130, statusGiven
```

I think there might be an easier way instead of counting the number of columns until `CS`.

Comment: Do you mean the position of the column might shift?  If it's fixed then the code you have seems fine.

Comment: I mean instead of counting the columns down until column CS, wouldn't it be easier to simply say CS, the column name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Column` property to return the column number:

```
With wb.Sheets("Profile")

    .Range("A1:DD500").AutoFilter .Columns("CS").Column, statusGiven

End With
```

Comment: If I wanted to filter by statusGiven and another statusGiven2 can I do it like `With wb.Sheets("Profile")

    .Range("A1:DD500").AutoFilter .Columns("CS").Column, statusGiven, statusGiven2

End With`

Comment: You need to pass `xlOr` (value = `2`) for the third param and then `statusGiven2`.

Comment: Ah so like this, `wb.Sheets("Profile") .Range("A1:DD500").AutoFilter xlOr=2 .Columns("CS").Column, statusGiven, statusGiven2`?

Comment: No. `With wb.Sheets("Profile") .Range("A1:DD500").AutoFilter .Columns("CS").Column, statusGiven, 2, statusGiven2`